# Trying to pass js value in Route Parameter : Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

**My route is here**

```
Route::get('/Service-Areas-Details/{ID}', 
    array(
        'uses'  => 'Web\ServiceAreas\ServiceAreaController@ServiceAreaDetails', 
        'as'    => 'ServiceAreaDetails'
    )
);
```

**Below is my code in Laravel.**

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $_token         =   "{!! csrf_token() !!}";

        var data = {
            "_token"        : $_token, 
        };
        $.ajax({
            url:            '{{URL::route("apiServiceAreas")}}',
            method:         "POST",
            async:          true,
            data:           JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType:    "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result) {
                $.each(result.Data, function( key, ServiceArea ) {
                    var URL = '{!! route("ServiceAreaDetails", ["ID" => 1]); !!}';
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**What is the point in discussion?**

Value = 1 in this code is static. Can we make it dynamic? `var URL = '{!! route("ServiceAreaDetails", ["ID" => 1]); !!}';`

**What's the problem?**

Route function is server side coding. Is there any way to pass js value inside loop to this server side function parameter?

Js value will be `ServiceArea.ID`

Comment: Tricky one. Best I can think of is to append it as a query parameter.
`var URL = '{{ route("ServiceAreaDetails"); }}?ID='+ServiceArea.ID;`

Comment: No. Because route param is not optional.

Comment: Well you would change your route to make it optional. Otherwise you can manually construct the URL. `var URL = '/areas/'+ServiceArea.ID;`

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution: Use 0 as a placeholder ID and replace it as needed.

Add restrictions to the regex as needed or use a more unique placeholder in case you are replacing the wrong part of the URL.

```
            $.each(result.Data, function( key, ServiceArea ) {
                var URL = '{!! route("ServiceAreaDetails", ["ID" => 0]); !!}';
                URL = URL.replace(/0/, ServiceArea.ID);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got it fixed using 2 options.

**Approach 1**

```
var asset = '{!! URL::asset("Service-Areas-Details") !!}';
```

**Approach 2**

By making the parameter optional as told by tanerkuc

```
Route::get('/Service-Areas-Details/{ID?}', 
    array(
        'uses'  => 'Web\ServiceAreas\ServiceAreaController@ServiceAreaDetails', 
        'as'    => 'ServiceAreaDetails'
    )
);
```